# ORA-01847 day of month must be between 1 and last day of month - Inserting date into Oracle Database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, netbeans

I am trying to enter information into a java program and store that information in an oracle database. But I am getting an error when trying to enter the date data.
This is the data I am trying to send:

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(id_text.getText());
    String name = name_text.getText();
    String dobt = id_text.getText();
    String address = addr_text.getText();
    int number = Integer.parseInt(num_text.getText());
    String gender = gender_text.getText();
    int club = Integer.parseInt(club_text.getText());
    int county = Integer.parseInt(county_text.getText());
    String date = date_text.getText();
    String type = type_text.getText();
```

I am entering the data into textfields and storing that data in the variables above. Then I am trying to send these variable values to my table with a preparedStatement like so:

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO player VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ps.setString(2, name);
            ps.setString(3, dobt); 
            ps.setString(4, address);
            ps.setInt(5, number);
            ps.setString(6, gender);
            ps.setInt(7, club);
            ps.setInt(8, county);
            ps.setString(9, date);
            ps.setString(10, type);
            int i = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Here is the table I am trying to insert to:

```
CREATE TABLE player
(
  member_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
  member_name VARCHAR2(70) NOT NULL,
  date_of_birth DATE,
  member_address VARCHAR2(300),
  contact_number INT NOT NULL,
  gender VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL CHECK(gender IN('f','m')),
  club_seeding INT NOT NULL,
  county_seeding INT NOT NULL,
  renewal_date DATE,
  m_type VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL CHECK(m_type IN('junior','student', 'senior', 'family', 'associate'))
);
```

I am fairly new to this, and can't find similar problems online. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please provide table structure...i suppose  is Datetime in DB

Comment: What values are you entering for DATE_OF_BIRTH and RENEWAL_DATE?

Comment: Im using the format YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 2):

I am rather surprised at the error your are getting after looking at the code, but error messages can sometimes be misleading or so vague one does not know what to think! But I think I can help...

First of all you are trying to put a *String* value into a *Date* column:

```
ps.setString(9, date);
```

It *should* be:

```
ps.setDate(9, date);
```

Of course at this point, the variable "date" is still a String variable... that just won't do!

You have to convert your string that contains the date into an *SQL* Date data type (a Java Date data type will not do the trick either)!

So, where you have the line:

```
String date = date_text.getText();
```

Replace it with:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
java.sql.Date date = (java.sql.Date)df.parse(date_text.getText());
```

In order to use the `SimpleDateFormat()` function, you will need to have the following line added with your other import statements (if its not there already):

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
```

That should do the trick. Of course if the locale, or the format you have the date in in your String is different you will need to adjust that info in the parameters of the `SimpleDateFormat()` function.

Also, you may want to change your variable named: `date` (even if it isn't a Java reserved word) to something that makes it clear what kind of date it is... something like: `createDate`, `updateDate`, `birthDate`.

Down the road, it pays off to take a little extra time to think about your naming of variables, classes, etc. clarity clarity clarity!  And besides making the code clearer to understand, you will not have the possibility that you may accidentally be trying to use a reserved word, or the name an existing class, etc.

Comment: The issue seems to be parsing the date to a string

Comment: Or vice versa actually

Answer (score 1):

I'd venture your Java code, your database and your user are not agreeing on what a properly-formatted date should look like. To verify this, set a breakpoint on your call to `Connection.prepareStatement()` and inspect the value of `date` and `dobt`.

I suggest changing the lines in the first code block

```
String dobt = id_text.getText();
String date = date_text.getText();
```

to

```
java.text.DateFormat formatter = java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance()
java.util.Date dobt = formatter.parse(
java.util.Date date = formatter.parse(date_text.getText());
```

and in the second block use

```
ps.setDate(3, dobt);
ps.setDate(9, date);
```

Read up on the [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) class for more info on parsing dates.

Also, after coding that, I'm wondering if you meant to extract `dobt` from `id_text`?

Comment: Im getting this error: unreported exception ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
on the line:

Comment: java.util.Date date = formatter.parse(date_text.getText());

Comment: New to Java, I take it. You need to read up on exception handling, but for now add a `throws ParseException` to the function that contains the above code. You will also need eventually to catch that exception, probably wherever you're catching the SQLExceptions the JDBC functions throw.